# visual c++ and C++ builder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

Can C++builder compile any c++ source files.

I don't have a good knowledge in c++. but i have some experience in delphi.
I like to use c++ but confused which one to use

I know that *cbuilder has vcl , easy to develop ,easy for delphi developer*

But my problem is can it compile any c++ files (vc++ and other source files).
is it compatible with vc++ (excluding MFC and VCL). Can i use any APIs with c++builder

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Builder or Visual Studio for native C++ development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437416/c-builder-or-visual-studio-for-native-c-development)

Comment: but my problem is ,Can i use any c++ APIs with c++builder

Comment: No, of course not. It's absolutely worthless as a C++ IDE, because it's incompatible with VC++ and you'd have to recompile every library in your Windows system first. I don't know why they still distribute that thing. </SARCASM>

Comment: @DevSolar Don't you just hate having to recompile windows? :P

Comment: Download a trial from the link on the right of this page: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder ('Try It Now' button, I think.)  You should be able to get an idea of any issues you run into within the 30-day time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find C++ Builder very comfy coming from Delphi if you don't care about MFC or .NET via C++/CLI etc and just want native C++ then either will work for you.  Visual Studio 2010 supports a lot of the new C++0x features which is pretty nice, although they don't have variadic templates yet.  I'm not sure how much of C++0x is in C++ Builder as yet but that could be worth looking into as a deciding factor.

Comment: +1.  You cannot use VC specific compiler extensions. Standard code should work.

Answer (score 3):

It should be able to compile any standards conforming code.  If the code uses extensions that another compiler provides, it will more than likely have problems.  VC++ has quite a few extensions that are on by default and so someone using that compiler might use them with out realizing what is going on(the same applies to G++ the other major C++ compiler out there.)

Answer (score 0):

You can download a free version of C++ Builder at www.embarcadero.com.  With that, you can test your libraries for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, C++Builder's support for more advanced C++ code is limited.  For example, many of Boost's libraries are unsupported in C++Builder, and I've often had to modify other open source libraries to get them to build properly in C++Builder (due to various bugs or limitations in C++Builder's compiler).  Simpler C++ code can work without any problems.

So, depending on what C++ libraries / source files / APIs you're wanting to use, getting them to work in C++Builder may be very straightforward, or it may take significant work.